# How to Write Exception in xls for seleniium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver

i have n number of functional test cases.

From Excel sheet, i am controlling the test cases which want to run. Eg. Test case 1 - Run, Test Case 2- No Run etc.

When i see Run in excel sheet for Test case 1, using switch statement, i am picking the relevant classname.methodname()

Each functional test cases is in try /catch method to return the result as pass/fail. If try block completely runs successfully at the end i given result as pass else catch block return me the result as fail.

My Mainclass calls this all..

If some test case fails, due to browser issues like protected mode on or zoom size is > 100. I am not able to figure it out the failure until i run the debug mode.

By any chance, can I catch every exception and write in to excel?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to write to Excel? Do you know how to catch exceptions? Do you know how to get the exception text? You should be able to easily google each of these three things and find answers that you can put together on your own to solve this problem. Once you do this... if you have an issue, please edit this question and show what you have tried and what the result was. Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE).